# Bash scripting: how to iterate through all drives?

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, bash-scripting, busybox

I have buildroot readonly bootable image, which is *normally* loaded via TFTP in PXE enviroment. Filesystem in unpacked into ram and remounted as rw. And accidentally I wished to boot it from a USB stick and modify root filesystem content. So I thought of a "patch" system.

In a readonly image I can embed some `/etc/init.d` script, that, upon start, checks for `/dev/sd??` drives, tries to mount them to `/mnt` (one at a time), seeks for `/mnt/patch.sh` script and executes it, then unmount and proceed to next drive.

So basically I want to iterate through all availble <s>drives</s> PARTITIONS in system. How to do that in shell script? (I use busybox)

In a `for` loop, does a `?` character in `/dev/sd??` meets `/dev/sda` for example (which i want to avoid)?

Answer (score 0):

[busybox shell](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/ash/#busybox) does not interpret bash.
The Debian [ash](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/ash) ([dash](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/ash/#dash)) variant 0.3.8-5 was incorporated with busybox release 0.52 (07/'01).

There are several differences between ash/dash and bash.

[ash man](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/ash/ash.1.en.html)